# Python slicing numpy array using another array as depth

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array with dimensions (x = 2, y = 2, z = 3), as shown below

```
a = [[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]],
    [[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]]
```

I want to get first N elements from each (x, y) element of a, where N is defined in another array of size x,y. E.g.

```
b = [[1,2],
     [0,0]]
```

The result would should be

```
c = [[[0,1],[3,4,5]],
    [[6],[9]]
```

How can I do this without loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mask over the elements in `a` that are within the given ranges and use this mask whenever you need to operate on `a`. If you want the encapsulate the mask and array in one entity, have a look at the [numpy.ma](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#the-numpy-ma-module) module.

```
a = np.array([[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]],
             [[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]])

b = np.array([[1,2],
              [0,0]])

mask = np.arange(3)[None,None,:] <= b[:,:,None]

a[mask]
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9])
```

But if you want the output as a non-homogeneous array, I cannot think of a better way to do that than using loops.

Comment: Nice one! All I'm doing is summing those values once they've been extracted so that should do the job. Thanks